# Using Selenium to Pin pictures to boards

Tags: java, selenium

Forgive me if I don't post something in the right way, as this is my first post to the site. I'm currently in the process of making a crawler (in java) for my school that visits a certain page on pinterest and "repins" all photos on it. I'm currently using Selenium to code this, but I've run into a problem with repetition. I know how to program to open a certain image and repin it, but how would I go about doing the same for other pictures? I have to do this for a variety of pinterest pages with variable amounts of pictures on each page. Here is the relevant code I have now:

`public static void GetPageInfo(WebDriver driver) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/kachance33/school-psych/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/a/div[2]/div/div
        ")).  click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[23]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[59]")).click();
}`

To help simplify my questions, here they are:

1. How do I have selenium click on various pictures where the xpath is different for each?
2. How do I put this all into a while loop?
3. How do I handle exceptions where the button or picture is not found? (without the whole program crashing and having to restart)

Comment: Take a gander at [SO's markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use driver.findElements() with an xpath or css selector that maps to a list of pictures (in the form of WebElements), and iterate through them.

I.e.

```
List<WebElement> pictures = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".GridItems .item"));

for (WebElement picture : pictures) {
    // code to pin the picture
}
```

Using driver.findElements() eliminates your concern in question #3 as well, since the method will not throw an exception. It would simply return an empty list if no pictures are found.